# Using Aurigma with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, aurigma

I am very new to Laravel and currently working on a project build on Laravel 5. i want to integrate Aurigma ImageUploaderFlash.class.php but cannot seem to put it in the right location.

I put all files in app\Libraries\imageuploader and in my controller I set

```
use ImageUploaderFlash;
```

But when I call to render the CSS in the public function edit() using

```
ImageUploaderFlash::renderCssRules();
```

I get an error

```
Class 'app\Libraries\imageuploader\ImageUploaderFlash' not found
```

So it knows where to look for it, but still cannot find it :\

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `ImageUploaderFlash.class.php` to `ImageUploaderFlash.php` , remove the class thing. Anyway it is an autoloading problem. Read more about that.

Comment: Many thanks Marius... I left .class in the file name and added the folder Libraries to autoload in composer... now I am not getting errors